# Search for largest number of matches in rexp in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching, match

I'm trying to search some arrays for the best possible matches. For instance, given the `@source` and `@search` lists:

```
my @source = ("John Ronald Reuel Tolkien","John Ronald S Tolkien","Trent Reznor","Barack Hussein Obama II","Barack Hussein II"); #note that the second item is wrong and should be discarded!
my @search = ("John Ronald Reuel T","Trent Reznor","Barack Hussein II","Barack Hussein Obama II","No match here");
```

I would like to associate the `@search` list with the best match in `@source` list. I'm figuring this can be done with a search pattern with several `OR`s, but I'm stuck. Please see my example below:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @source = ("John Ronald Reuel Tolkien","John Ronald S Tolkien","Trent Reznor","Barack Hussein Obama II","Barack Hussein II");
my @search = ("John Ronald Reuel T","Trent Reznor","Barack Hussein II","Barack Hussein Obama II","No match here");

print "twonames\t\talternativesearch\n";
foreach my $s (@search){
    #gets first two names
    (my $twonames=$s)=~s/^(\w+ \w+).*$/$1/;

    #gets all other names, if they exist
    (my $others=$s)=~s/^(\w+ \w+)//;
    if ($others){
        #deletes initial space
        (my $alternativesearch=$others)=~s/^\s//;
        $alternativesearch=~s/\s/\|/g;
        print "$twonames\t\t$alternativesearch\n";
    }
    else {
        print "$twonames\t\tNO OTHER NAMES PRESENT\n";
    }
}
    #prints
    # twonames                alternativesearch
    # John Ronald             R|Tolkien
    # Trent Reznor            NO OTHER NAMES PRESENT
    # Barack Hussein          II
    # Barack Hussein          Obama|II
```

In this search I would like to have an association between @search items and @source items that would yield the best match. Something like:

```
# search                    source
# John Ronald Reuel T       John Ronald Reuel Tolkien
# Trent Reznor              Trent Reznor
# Barack Hussein Obama II   Barack Hussein Obama II
# No match here
```

Note that, in the case of Obama it matched the whole array, in the first line it matched the two first words plus something else, and in the last case it found nothing. How would you proceed to find the best match?
Thanks

Edit: This was crossposted [on PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1102921).
Edit2: Even though I used people's names in my example, my real case has no people's names in case that matters.

Comment: Have you looked on cpan for word-matching/fuzzy matching modules? There are already a number out there, and unless you have a specific definition of "best match" (e.g. whole word matches are fine, but no partial word matches; smallest Levenshtein distance between strings), you can save yourself a lot of time by using an existing module.

Comment: great! I'll look for that! thanks!

Comment: Crossposted: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1102921

Comment: @choroba - thanks, I edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your definition of 'best match' is simple length, which it seems like it is from your examples, then you could also just sort your `@source` array by reverse length and then if you match one of them you just skip the rest. Labels are handy for controlling the two loops:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @source = ("John Ronald Reuel Tolkien","John Ronald S Tolkien","Trent Reznor","Barack Hussein Obama II","Barack Hussein II");
my @search = ("John Ronald Reuel T","Trent Reznor","Barack Hussein II","Barack Hussein Obama II","No match here");

# print header line
printf "%-32s\t%-32s\n", 'search', 'source';

search:
for my $se (@search) {

    source:
    for my $so (reverse sort {length($a) <=> length($b)} @source) {

        if ($so =~ /^\Q$se\E/) {
            printf "%-32s\t%-32s\n", $se, $so;
            next search;
        }
    }
    print "No match here\n";
}
```

Output:

```
$ perl myscript.pl
search                                  source
John Ronald Reuel T                     John Ronald Reuel Tolkien
Trent Reznor                            Trent Reznor
Barack Hussein II                       Barack Hussein II
Barack Hussein Obama II                 Barack Hussein Obama II
No match here
$
```

You really don't need regular expressions or pattern matching to do this, and it would be faster without. There's only one regular expression above, it's case-sensitive and it's anchored to the beginning of the string. Therefore we can use `substr` for that instead. It's arguably easier/more maintainable, but definitely more efficient (it's more than twice as fast in my Benchmark):

```
        if (substr($so, 0, length($se)) eq $se) {
```